# Centre of mass with double integration. What is Moment $Mx$?

Tags: integration, centroid, moment-problem

First post here. I'm having serious trouble understanding how the Moment $Mx$ is solved for in a typical Centre of Mass problem.
So, many people online, are teaching methods to solve for $Mx$ that are completely different from each other.
And these different methods give different results!

Some solve the 'Moment' $Mx$ as

$$Mx = \int \frac{y}{2} [ f(x) ]^2 - [ g(x) ]^2~\mathrm{d}x$$

Something like this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SWu_i-19Rn0

And some others solve the moment $Mx$ as

$$Mx = \iint y \rho(x ,y)~\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$$

Like this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yJDRwKGfKDs

Which is the correct one?

Or are they both related to two different things?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Learning from videos is a risky thing. You're missing the context in your questions. The first is in the setting of single-variable calculus and a special sort of region. The second is in the setting of multivariable calculus.

Comment: Would you please dumb it down for me?
Both these methods are solving for centre of mass and both use integrals. Are there two different sets of formulae depending on how many variables are involved?

Comment: It looks like you copied the first formula incorrectly. The $y$ should be $\rho$, representing the density. And that formula is meant to be used when the density is constant throughout the region whose moment you want to know.

Answer (score 1):

The center of mass $(x,y)_{\rm CoM}$ of a suitable region $R$ with mass $M$ has coordinates equal to the [average values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_of_a_function) of $x$ and $y$ over $R$.

$$x_{\rm CoM} = \frac{\displaystyle \iint_R x\rho\,dA}{\displaystyle \iint_R\rho\,dA}, y_{\rm CoM} = \frac{\displaystyle \iint_R y\,\rho\,dA}{\displaystyle\iint_R\rho\,dA}$$

The numerators are the moments of $R$ about the $y$-axis ($M_y$) and $x$-axis ($M_x$), respectively.

If $R$ is suitable enough to express it as the set

$$R = \{(x,y) \mid a\le x\le b \text{ and } g(x)\le y\le f(x)\}$$

then

$$M_x = \int_a^b \int_{g(x)}^{f(x)} y\rho(x,y)\,dy\,dx$$

Suppose density is constant, $\rho(x,y)=\rho$. Then

$$M_x = \rho \int_a^b \int_{g(x)}^{f(x)} y\,dy\,dx = \rho\int_a^b \frac{y^2}2\bigg|_{y=g(x)}^{y=f(x)}\,dx = \frac\rho2 \int_a^b \bigg(f(x)^2 - g(x)^2\bigg)\,dx$$

Comment: Wow! Thank you so so much! God bless you. 
That literally cleared all my doubts!

Comment: So its safe to say that the first one refers to regions with variable densities and the second one refers to a Centroid (constant densities/Geometric center)?